# Automatically inserting value from another table in lightswitch

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-lightswitch

I am creating a desktop, C# application in Lightswitch. I have a DB file with a table called Reports and another table called StatusList. There are going to be 3 options in StatusList table - Unresolved, In Progress and Resolved. The Report table has a couple of not important fields and a field "Status", which is supposed to hold one of the three values from StatusList table

Now, when the user will create a new Report, I need the application to automatically insert the "Unresolved" value as the "Status" without user being able to change it.

I have tried using this method

```
partial void Reports_Created()
    {
        this.Status = "Unresolved";
    }
```

but it is not working. I guess it is because I am trying to assign a String value to the field which is populated from another table.

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and this is my first Lightswitch app as well.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your trying to pass parameters between screens. Beth Massi does a good job explaining how to achieve that in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NYuiH9H5cYQ). And [here is another MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6aec65c1-32e4-4f8d-aef2-5cef4160e3a9/how-to-pass-a-parameter-in-lightswitch-add-screen) link to a similar question

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't your code before like:
This.report.status = "Unresolved"

I.e. The report entity is not referenced by "this" (that refers to the screen).